# Error en parámetros de CRUD frontend en Spring Boot 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud, frontend

Tengo los siguientes códigos para realizar un CRUD en Spring Boot 4, pero a la hora de actualizar, no aparece el formulario que se necesita y aparece el siguiente error:

> Required parameter 'nombres' is not present.
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'nombres' for method parameter type String is not present

```
@PostMapping(path = "/update/{id}")
public @ResponseBody String actualizar(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String nombres,
        @RequestParam String apellidos, @RequestParam String especialidad, @RequestParam String telefono,
        @RequestParam String email) {
    Odontologo o = buscarId(id);
    o.setNombres(nombres);
    o.setApellidos(apellidos);
    o.setEspecialidad(especialidad);
    o.setTelefono(telefono);
    o.setEmail(email);

    odontologoRepository.save(o);

    return "listo";
}

@GetMapping("/update_frontend/{id}")
public String mostrarFormularioActualizacion(@PathVariable int id) {
    return "formularioActualizarOdontologo";
}

@PostMapping("/update_frontend/{id}")
public @ResponseBody String actualizar(@PathVariable int id, @RequestParam String nombres,
        @RequestParam String apellidos, @RequestParam String especialidad, @RequestParam String telefono,
        @RequestParam String email, Model model) {
    Odontologo o = buscarId(id);
    o.setNombres(nombres);
    o.setApellidos(apellidos);
    o.setEspecialidad(especialidad);
    o.setTelefono(telefono);
    o.setEmail(email);

    odontologoRepository.save(o);

    model.addAttribute("mensaje", "Odontólogo actualizado correctamente");
    return "respuestaActualizacionOdontologo";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/find")     
    public @ResponseBody Odontologo buscarId(@RequestParam int id) {        
    return odontologoRepository.findById(id).get();     
}
```

no sé por qué sale este error ni cómo solucionarlo, el siguiente código es el html de actualizar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Actualizar Odontólogo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Actualizar Odontólogo</h1>
    <form th:action="@{'/odontologo/update_frontend/' + ${odontologo.id}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombres">Nombres:</label>               
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombres" name="nombres" required>
                required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos"
                th:value="${odontologo.apellidos}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="especialidad">Especialidad:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="especialidad" name="especialidad"
                th:value="${odontologo.especialidad}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" th:value="${odontologo.telefono}"
                required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" th:value="${odontologo.email}"
                required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        <a href="/odontologo/all_frontend" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Volver al Listado</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

cualquier otro código que necesiten lo puedo proporcionar

Comment: revisaste que el objeto que estas tratando de actualizar tenga todos los datos completos? trata de hacer un debug de la aplicacion y ver la trama de llamas de los endpoint